# Error creating site from template with feature with module

Tags: visual-studio, feature, site-template, ssom, module

I created with Visual Studio a **module** to uploade a file.

And a **feature** associated.

Currently the site has this **feature desactivated**.

I create a **site template** based on this site.

When I **create a site based on that template** I get error saying it can not create an instance of the file from the module. And cannot find the path to the souce of the feature.

Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, found the problem.

I was making some test with a module and a feature in development environment.

I was changing the url where the file of the module were dployed.

When I open SharePoint Manager 2010, I found the some file in diferentes places.

I delete all missing files.

Then worked perfectly.